# Windows: Print 2 separate images on opposite side of paper

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, images

I have 2 images I need to print. I want the 1st of the 2 files to appear on one side of the paper and the other image on the opposite side.

Obviously you can print the first image onto one side, flip the paper over and print the 2nd side but how can I have both images print on both sides in a single print job?

I have a duplex printer and am running Windows 7. Both images are just 2 separate PNG files of the same dimensions.

Comment: Select the two files, press print. In the print dialogue box, right-bottom corner, there's **Options**, in which select **Printer Properties**, there, depending on the printer, is an option to do what you want. At least I have it.

Comment: This worked for me, from this menu I could select 2-sided printing and both of them printed onto opposite sides of the same sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select the two pictures.
- Press **Print**
- In the **Print** dialogue box, at the bottom-right corner , there's a button labelled [image: Options], click it.
- Another dialogue box opens:
  [image: Printer properties]
- Hit **Printer Properties**, it should take you to the Printer's Print Dialogue box, there should be an option to do what you want (It might be named **Two-Sided(Duplex) Printing/Print On Both Sides**).